# Outputting content from JTable onto TextArea using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

So I am attempting to make a basic GUI using Java Swing. I have some buttons, a text field with an enter button and also a larger text area. When clicking the button "Display all teams", the action listener for this button should output the JTable content onto the text area, however it isn't working and nothing is outputting.

```
package footballmanager;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class FootballGUI 
    {
        private JFrame frame;
        private JTextField textField;


    //Launch the application.
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FootballGUI window = new FootballGUI();
        window.frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    //Display the application
       public void displayGUI() {
       this.frame.setVisible(true);
   }
    
    //Create the application.
            
    public FootballGUI() 
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 611, 471);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        // Text area
        final JTextArea testArea = new JTextArea(5,20);
        testArea.setBounds(6, 6, 329, 343);
        frame.getContentPane().add(testArea);
        
        // Buttons on the window
        JButton displayTeams = new JButton("Display all teams");
        // (x, y, w, h)
        displayTeams.setBounds(370, 6, 200, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(displayTeams);
        
        
        class MyActionListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//                    String s = String.format("%s %s", "Club name", "Club points");
//                    testArea.setText(s);
                        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                                "Last Name",
                                                "Sport",
                                                "# of Years",
                                                "Vegetarian"};
                                            Object[][] data = {
                        {"Kathy", "Smith",
                         "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
                        {"John", "Doe",
                         "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
                        {"Sue", "Black",
                         "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
                        {"Jane", "White",
                         "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
                        {"Joe", "Brown",
                         "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
                    };
                         JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
                         
                         DefaultTableModel model1 = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                         int nRow = model1.getRowCount(), nCol = model1.getColumnCount();
                         Object [][] tableData = new Object [nRow] [nCol];
                         for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++){
                             for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++){
                             tableData [i][j] = model1.getValueAt (i,j);
                             testArea.append((String) tableData [i][j] + "\t");
                             }
                         }
                         testArea.append("\n");
                 
                 
                }
        }
            
        displayTeams.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
        
        JButton goalSort = new JButton("Sort list by goals");
        goalSort.setBounds(370, 40, 200, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(goalSort);

        JButton winSort = new JButton("Sort list by most wins");
        winSort.setBounds(370, 74, 200, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(winSort);

        JButton randomMatch = new JButton("Generate random match");
        randomMatch.setBounds(370, 280, 200, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(randomMatch);
        
        JButton displayMatches = new JButton("Display all played matches");
        displayMatches.setBounds(370, 314, 200, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(displayMatches);

        JButton btnEnter = new JButton("Search for a match");
        btnEnter.setBounds(518, 404, 85, 39);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnEnter);

        JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar();
        scrollBar.setBounds(320, 6, 15, 338);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollBar);
        
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(5, 410, 508, 28);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        
        JLabel lblMapGoesHere = new JLabel("List goes here");
        lblMapGoesHere.setBounds(342, 37, 263, 312);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblMapGoesHere);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your last question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65136436/java-swing-actioneventlistener-not-working-upon-button-click/65136497#65136497) you were specifically advised to NOT use a null layout and to use layout manager instead to avoid problems. Why have you not listened to the advice? Why should people continue to answer if you continue to ignore the advice given?

Comment: Swing components may not function as expected if they are not part of the UI, they are not intended as general purpose data structures. Try using System.out.print to ensure that your text is being generated correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I redid your GUI to use a `JTable`.

Here's what the revised GUI looks like.

[image: Football GUI]

Here's what it looks like after you left-click on the "Display All Teams" button.

[image: Football GUI 2]

Here are the major changes I made to your GUI.

1. I started the Java application with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and used on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. I used [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for the two `JPanels` I created.  The JFrame content pane uses a default `BorderLayout`.  The `JTable` `JPanel` uses the default `FlowLayout`.  the `JButton` `JPanel` uses a `GridBagLayout`.  The fixed layout you used wouldn't let me adjust the size of the `JTextArea` you were using.
3. I used a `JTable` to display the teams.  I put the `JTable` in a `JScrollPane`, and the `JScrollPane` inside a JPanel.
4. I created the columns and data before I created the GUI.  Generally, you want to create the application model first, then the GUI.  This is a simple example of the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.

Here's the complete runnable code I used.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class FootballGUI implements Runnable {

    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;
    private String[][] data;

    // Launch the application.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new FootballGUI());
    }

    public FootballGUI() {
        String[] columnNames = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", 
                "# of Years", "Vegetarian" };
        this.model = new DefaultTableModel();

        for (String s : columnNames) {
            model.addColumn(s);
        }

        this.data = new String[][] { { "Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", "5", "false" },
                { "John", "Doe", "Rowing", "3", "true" }, 
                { "Sue", "Black", "Knitting", "2", "false" },
                { "Jane", "White", "Speed reading", "20", "true" }, 
                { "Joe", "Brown", "Pool", "10", "false" } };
    }

    // Create the application.
    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Football GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createTablePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.AFTER_LINE_ENDS);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createTablePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        table = new JTable(model);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(scrollPane);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.weightx = 1.0d;

        JButton displayTeams = new JButton("Display all teams");
        displayTeams.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
        panel.add(displayTeams, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton goalSort = new JButton("Sort list by goals");
        panel.add(goalSort, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton winSort = new JButton("Sort list by most wins");
        panel.add(winSort, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton randomMatch = new JButton("Generate random match");
        panel.add(randomMatch, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton displayMatches = new JButton("Display all played matches");
        panel.add(displayMatches, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton btnEnter = new JButton("Search for a match");
        panel.add(btnEnter, gbc);

        return panel;
    }

    public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            int count = model.getRowCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                model.removeRow(0);
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                model.addRow(data[i]);
            }
        }

    }
    
}
```

Comment: FYI the OP was advised to use layout managers in his last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65136436/java-swing-actioneventlistener-not-working-upon-button-click/65136497#65136497

Comment: @camickr: Thanks for the heads-up.  The OP will not be the only person to read this question and answer.

Comment: Ok, so I am trying to implement the JTable and JScrollpane of your code into my code. However I am getting errors for  model.removeRow(0), model.addColumn(s) and this.model = new DefaultTableModel() with the errors stating that it cannot find the symbols for these. Please see the edited code.

Comment: @JesleyNB: That's because you don't define the DefaultTableModel in your class.  I provided working code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> however it isn't working

Well, you have a ClassCastException. Don't you think it is important to put that information in the question?

```
 JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
 
 DefaultTableModel model1 = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
 int nRow = model1.getRowCount(), nCol = model1.getColumnCount();
 Object [][] tableData = new Object [nRow] [nCol];
 for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++){
     for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++){
     tableData [i][j] = model1.getValueAt (i,j);
     testArea.append((String) tableData [i][j] + "\t");
     }
 }
```

What is the point of logic like above?

Why would you add data to a JTable where the data is displayed nicely formatted  and then attempt to copy and display it in a JTextArea, where the data is not formatted?

Why would you take data from the model and attempt to add the data to a 2D Array?

Why are you even trying to access the TableModel?

You can just get the information from the JTable directly. All you need is:

```
//testArea.append((String) tableData [i][j] + "\t");
testArea.append( table.getValueAt(i, j).toString() + "\t" )?
```

Of course you will also need two loops, one for rows and one for columns.

Comment: Yeah I realised it's much more efficient to just output the table itself so I got rid of the JTextArea. Please see edited code as I made some changes but am having errors for model.removeRow(0), model.addColumn(s) and this.model = new DefaultTableModel() with the errors stating that it cannot find the symbols for these.

Comment: @JesleyNB, One question per posting. You already have working code so this question has been answered. If you have a new issue the ask a new question with a new [mre] demonstrating the problem.